# Usage of maverick as an adjective for a thing

Tags: grammar, word-usage, phrases

I saw on Google the formulation: "the maverick of the sea scrolls…".

Would it be better, equivalent or incorrect, instead of saying for example "the maverick of frameworks", to say "the maverick framework" or the "the frameworks' maverick"?

EDIT
Actually I want to know if I can use correctly the shorter sentence: "the maverick framework", as it is using maverick as an adjective?

Thanks!

Comment: Do these answer your question/s? [Attributive nouns vs. of-genitive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/274944/attributive-nouns-vs-of-genitive); [Why do we say _a hotel room_ and not _a hotel's room?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/159545/why-do-we-say-a-hotel-room-and-not-a-hotels-room/159560#159560) Essentially, none is incorrect, but here, your first variant sounds magisterial and your second most natural.

Comment: More precisely I'm interested to know if maverick can be used as an adjective for a thing, as in "the maverick framework", since it is a bit more consise / direct for a punchy title :)

Comment: I suggest  you check Merriam Webster. It's pretty clear there. No, maverick cannot refer to a thing. [I'm interested in knowing whether etc.]

Comment: So the book titled "The Maverick Of The Dead Sea Scrolls" is a wrong usage? or is it just the form "The Maverick Dead Sea Scrolls" that would be incorrect?

Comment: Any noun or adjective may be used figuratively, which would cover your title.

Comment: Yes, it is used in non-sentient situations. Ignore from-the-hip, unreferenced claims. Google "a maverick planet, Pluto" (it was still a planet in 1971), "maverick Pluto" etc. // "... occasionally nerves and veins take maverick pathways and show up in unexpected places."
— Virginia Holman, Double Take, Winter 2002. (quoted as an example by M-W) Note that genericisation has taken place, so that the 'm' may be lower-cased.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thank you, that's my answer!