# Tooth removal vs removing a tooth / molars removal vs removing of molars

Tags: word-order

I have a dentistry student who writes things like: "the need for molars removal" and "molar removal treatment" which sounds off to me. I prefer to say (write) "the need to remove molars" and "treatment involving removal of molars", which sound more 'direct' to me.

Yet, I am struggling to explain why my version is more direct.

I'd be most obliged for any pointers...

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Attributive nouns vs. of-genitive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/274944/attributive-nouns-vs-of-genitive) (related; this hinges on formality and idiomaticity rather than grammar).  Here, your "the need to remove molars" sounds _far_ more idiomatic. But "molar removal treatment" is far more punchy (and direct).

Comment: I'll add that the singular-form attributive, _the need for molar removal_, is probably as natural sounding as your variant.

Comment: I think "extraction" rather than "removal" is far more idiomatic in US dental jargon.

Answer (score 1):

You are right.  "the need for molar removal" sounds wrong, especially as 'molar's a different specialist meaning chemistry and chemical engineering.  "The need to remove a molar" or "extract a molar" is concise and precise

Comment: OP is asking in relation to works on dentistry. And the first 30 Google hits I found for "molar removal" speak of the relevant teeth.