# "Taiwan" as an adjective versus "Taiwanese"

Tags: grammar, differences, adjectives

I hope this question is not too simplistic for the "linguists ..." forum, but I couldn’t seem to find an answer elsewhere.

I am helping a non-native speaker proofread his Ph.D. dissertation regarding archeology in Taiwan. Is it acceptable to use “Taiwan archeology” instead of “Taiwanese archeology” (as in “the history of Taiwan archeology”) for archeological work conducted in Taiwan but not necessarily by Taiwanese (e.g., during the Japanese occupation)?

And if it is to refer to the discipline of archeology as developed in Taiwan by Taiwanese academics, would it not then need to be “Taiwanese archeology”?

I suppose “archeology in Taiwan” or “the archeology of Taiwan” could be used, but he has consistently used “Taiwan + NP” (e.g., “Taiwan indigenous people”) throughout the work, and I’d like to know if such is ever acceptable.

Comment: Personally I would prefer "The archeology of Taiwan" to "Taiwan archeology". "Taiwan archeology" sounds to me like a private sector company based in Taiwan that deals in archeology, archeological tours or equipment for archeology.

Comment: I'd agree with @BoldBen that 'the archeology of Taiwan' sounds more usual here. 'Taiwanese archeology' to my UK ears does indeed sound like it's referring to the discipline as practised (this includes scholarship/theory) by Taiwanese archeologists rather than the archeology carried out in Taiwan.  And the use of a Saxon genitive probably sounds too informal. // This addresses one such choice. I'd probably use 'the indigenous Taiwanese' in the second example you cite. But the choices hereabouts are not simple ones. // I'd give an 'answer' instead of a comment but have no exact references.

Comment: Related: [Can one explain the different distributions of the Saxon and the analytic genitive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30385/can-one-explain-the-different-distributions-of-the-saxon-and-the-analytic-norma), [Attributive nouns vs of-genitive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/274944/attributive-nouns-vs-of-genitive),  and [Attributive ... or possessive noun? 'the Dell Company's staff' or 'the Dell Company staff'?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114531/attributive-or-possessive-noun-the-dell-companys-staff-or-the-dell-company-st).