# What is it called when instead of saying, for example, an "English book," you say a "book of English"?

Tags: nouns

I couldn't find this sort of question anywhere, but this is similar to possession, like when you say "Amanda's book" instead of "the book of Amanda," but those two have slightly different meanings.
What's it called when you make the noun go after the word "of" and it describes the first noun?

Comment: The words "English" and "Amanda" aren't adjectives.

Comment: [noun phrase + of](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/possession-john-s-car-a-friend-of-mine)

Comment: HippoSawrUs yeah my mistake but i mean like the latter noun describes the former noun so its kind of like an adjective

Comment: It's just a possessive construction "**It is the horse of the king**" vs "**The king's horse**" P.S `What's it called when you make the noun go after the word "of" and it describes the first noun?` The king does not describe the "first noun" i.e. *horse*

Comment: _Book of English_ by itself doesn't have a clear meaning - only as part of a title such as _The Oxford Book of English Verse_.

Comment: These answer your question: [Can one explain the different distributions of the Saxon and the analytic (Norman) (periphrastic, 'of') genitive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30385/can-one-explain-the-different-distributions-of-the-saxon-and-the-analytic-norma) // [Attributive nouns vs of-genitives](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/274944/attributive-nouns-vs-of-genitive/610009#610009):  the _analytic_ or _Norman_ or _periphrastic_ or  'of'-genitive.

Answer (score 0):

Compare:

> A recipe book

and

> A book of recipes

If you look in either book you will find recipes.   Attributive adjectival **recipe book** indicates the category in which the book belongs and **book of recipes** refers to its contents in the plural.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question since you're not providing a term for phrases like "book of recipes".

Comment: @Laurel - you may want to see [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/445525) in case you'd like to respond. The poster seems to want you to see it.